# how to achive fail safe behaviour of iterator

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Iterators have a behaviour like 'fail safe' and 'fail fast'. I am learning about 'fail safe' iterator. One can achieve it using CopyOnWriteArrayList,ConcurrentHashMap classes.
My doubt is, is there any other classes through which we can also achieve 'fail safe' behaviour of iterator. Are the classes under java.util.concurrent package help to achieve 'fail safe' iterator?

Answer (score 1):

we can also achive fail safe behaviour of iterator using classes like ConcurrentSkipListSet etc,which is present under java.util.concurrent package.